# can not connect to PostgreSQL database using npgsql

Tags: visual-studio-2017, npgsql

I tried 10 different npgsql version and entity framework using visual studio 2017 to get connected to PostgreSQL database but every time  I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly "System.ValueTuple,version=4.0.3.0

Even if I install this, I still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what should i do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my bad,missed dictation ,sorry

Comment: You really need to post your csproj, otherwise nobody will be able to help you...

Comment: @ShayRojansky so happy to see your comment here,can you please tell me how can create a manual mapping (database first)using npgsql?is there such a possibility?

Comment: Your questions are really unclear... Are you using EF 6.x or EF Core? Which version? For EF Core database-first, have you already read [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html#using-an-existing-database-database-first)?

Comment: @ShayRojansky EF 4.5

Comment: Did you install Npgsql via Nuget?  If not, I'd recommend you do.